# Puppet + Beaker + Travis: acceptance test failing

Tags: puppet, travis-ci, beaker

I A have a Puppet module with acceptance tests based on Beaker. The module is working fine and when running locally all the acceptance tests run fine. But when I run the tests on Travis I got the following error in the module execution:

```
/Stage[main]/Alfred::Services/Service[alfred]: Could not evaluate: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Alfred is a system service based on upstart that is part of my module.
I am using Puppet 4.3.2. Here is the travis build: https://travis-ci.org/nicopaez/alfred-puppet

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, there's a few issues.

One is that the environment variable you're using in Travis doesn't set the Puppet version. You need to add that code to your `spec_helper_acceptance.rb`:

```
hosts.each do |host|
  install_puppet_on(host,
    :puppet => ENV['PUPPET_VERSION'] || '4.3.2',
  )
end
```

Right now it's still installing Puppet 3.8 (the default latest)

For further information on what is actually causing the issues in Travis, [I forked your repo and did a build](https://travis-ci.org/petems/alfred-puppet/builds/120148741) where I enabled the debug and trace options for beaker:

```
result = apply_manifest(pp, :trace => true, :debug => true)
```

From this, looking at the Travis build, theres an issue with the git clone exec:

```
Debug: Exec[clone-repo](provider=posix): Executing 'git clone https://github.com/fiuba/alfred.git /var/www/alfred'
  Debug: Executing 'git clone https://github.com/fiuba/alfred.git /var/www/alfred'
  Notice: /Stage[main]/Alfred::App/Exec[clone-repo]/returns: fatal: Could not change back to '/root': Permission denied
  Error: git clone https://github.com/fiuba/alfred.git /var/www/alfred returned 128 instead of one of [0]
```

You could fix this by using the `vcsrepo` module, which performs git clones in an more idempotent way:

```
vcsrepo { '/var/www/alfred':
  ensure   => present,
  source   => 'https://github.com/fiuba/alfred.git',
  provider => git,
  user     => 'deployer',
}
```

There's a few other fixes, I'm PRing some fixes to your module to fix them, and will add a summary here to the Stack Overflow answer after you've reviewed and merged, as some are significant refactors with a few different approaches.

Comment: Thanks @peter but I think you are working on master branch where the build works because the tests checks basic stuff. Please take a look at "fix-travis" branch where there are several tests and you will see the error I am reporting.